# webmatrix and ASP.NET Web Helpers Library 1.1

Tags: webmatrix

Can someone explain what happens when you install this package
Is it just a dll that is added somewhere?
Also is it possible to view the source for the helpers contained in this package.
Have searched the web but cant see any reference to source
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bin folder is created and a DLL is added to it. You can use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) to look at the decompiled source code, although Reflector will not last long so you had better hurry. the docs for a number of the helpers can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/asp-net-web-pages-api-reference#Helpers)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the assembly is added to your WebMatrix project. You must install the helper library from the feed into each project that needs the helper library functionality (details below). The ASP.NET Web Helpers Library 1.1 includes several helpers, most of these helpers are explained in the WebMatrix online book at www.asp.net/webmatrix. The ASP.NET Web Helpers Library 1.1 also installs the Twitter helper and the Facebook helper. If you wish, you can install the Twitter helper and the Facebook helper independantly. You can view the assembly using Reflector, or if you have Visual Studio you can use the Visual Studio Object Browser, see the post [Understanding WebMatrix Helpers using Visual Studio's Object Browser](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erikreitan/archive/2010/07/14/understanding-webmatrix-helpers-using-visual-studio-s-object-browser.aspx) for more details. There's also the managed reference content on MSDN that will help you navigate the helper library code, see the [Microsoft.Web.Helpers Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.helpers%28VS.99%29.aspx) for details. The descriptions will be updated soon, however the syntax is all available now.

The following procedure shows how to use the Administration tool to install the ASP.NET Web Helpers Library. You will use some of these helpers in this tutorial and other tutorials in this series.

1.In WebMatrix, click the Site workspace.

2.In the content pane, click ASP.NET Web Pages Administration. This loads an administration page into your browser. Because this is the first time you're logging into the administration page, it prompts you to create a password.

3.Create a password. 
After you click Create Password, a security-check page that looks like the following screen shot prompts you to rename the password file for security reasons. If this is your first time to see this page, do not try to rename the file yet. Proceed to the next step and follow the directions there.

4.Leave the browser open on the security-check page, return to WebMatrix, and click the Files workspace.

5.Right-click main project folder for your site and then click Refresh. The list of files and folders now displays an App_Data folder. Open that and you see an Admin folder. The newly created password file (_Password.config) is displayed in the ./App_Data/Admin/ folder.

6.Rename the file to Password.config by removing the leading underscore (_) character.

7.Return to the security-check page in the browser, and click the Click Here link near the end of the message about renaming the password file.

8.Log into the Administration page using the password you created. The page displays the Package Manager, which contains a list of add-on packages.

9.Find the ASP.NET Web Helpers Library 1.1 package, click the Install button, and then install the package as directed. When you install the ASP.NET Web Helpers library, the Package Manager also installs the FaceBook.Helper 1.0 library.